# How to Use Multiple "Application class" in android?

Tags: android, eclipse, android-layout, android-studio, android-manifest

See below My Manifest.xml

I  Already used ApplicationLoader.

```
<application
        android:name=".ui.ApplicationLoader"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/app_icon"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

<application
        android:name="org.abtollc.sdk.AbtoApplication"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
```

Now i want to use both application class in single project ? How its possible

**org.abtollc.sdk.AbtoApplication** is third-party libs.

Comment: Why would you want to use multiple `Application` classes? What scenario you have? Most possibly you can solve it using inheritance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not impossible, your `ApplicationLoader` must extend `AbtoApplication` in this case.

Answer (score 1):

According to Android documentation manifest file with only one application element is valid.

Answer (score 1):

Android application can handle only 1 application class,if you want multiple application class, you have to extend ApplicationLoader class from AbtoApplication class.

Answer (score 0):

You simply can't. Try extending `AbtoApplication` from your application class.